# The resource cannot be found. MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

The error is as follows:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Home/Offers
```

I'm programming a web app in MVC using Visual Studio 2013, I did not modify anything else except the HomeController.cs file.

HomeController.cs:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Pid = "page1";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Pid = "page6";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Book()
        {
            ViewBag.Pid = "page3";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Book2()
        {
            ViewBag.Pid = "page3";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Offers()
        {
            ViewBag.Pid = "page2";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Safety()
        {
            ViewBag.Pid = "page5";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Services()
        {
            ViewBag.Pid = "page4";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

My View folder:

```
Views
    Account
    Home
        Book.cshtml
        Book2.cshtml
        Contract.cshtml
        Index.cshtml
        Offers.cshtml
        Safety.cshtml
        Services.cshtml
    Shared
```

Except the first three cshtml file that the template comes with which is Index, Contract, & About(changed to Book), every other file that I add does not work.

Please help~~~~

*Edit:
RouteConfig.cs:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: The route is the default one.

Comment: It sounds like your site isn't being compiled before you are running it, so none of the changes in the controller are recognized. Check your configuration manager to ensure the site in question is active for build when you debug. You can also manually build it by right clicking the project node in Solution Explorer and clicking "Build".

Comment: @NightOwl888, that's the problem! Thanks a lot~! But why would it be inactive for build when debugging?

Comment: I guess we'll never know